# that as conjunction

Tags: conjunctions, relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

According to https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/that,
the article introduces `that` as a form of conjunction.
However, it seems to me that the following two sentences do not have same structures.

For example, sentence 1 seems to have two sentences "She is convinced" and another "he is British," which make sense when using independently.
However, int the sentence 2, one of the sentence two does not seem to  form a standalone sentence as in "I believe"(I believe what?)

How come we consider them as same syntactic structures?

1. She is convinced `that` he is British.
2. I believe `that` it is true.

Comment: That's not how it works. In 1. although "she is convinced" could stand alone grammatically, it is here not a clause, only part of one. Thus there are two clauses: a matrix clause (the sentence as a whole) and the embedded subordinate clause "that he is British". The same structure applies to your second example.

Comment: 'I believe' is an acceptable sentence according to some, though many would say that there is an understood direct object, prepositional phrase, or that-clause, and all would say that some sort of context would be helpful to aid the poor reader. But exactly the same sort of thing is true for 'She is convinced' (understood or missing that-clause etc).

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I feel like "that" in the sentence 2 looks like an objective pronoun and this confuses me all the time. From your comments, "I believe" could stand alone grammatically, but they cannot form a meaningful clause. 
To sum up, we see something is missing before "that". 
Am I right?

Comment: One more question: Is it possible to use conjunctive "that" after a sentence that does not lack anything?(Except relative pronoun)